# Problem with moving DNN website from win server 2003 to win server 2008 r2

Tags: iis-7, installation, windows-server-2008, dotnetnuke

I have a dnn site I host. It was hosted initially on a win 2003 server.
Now I want to move it to Win 2008 server. It was on a different hdd then win2003 os (userdata hdd) so I installed it in 2008 machine, installed database, created the site under IIS7 and poinyted to the website folder.
But when I want to access the website, it automatically redirects me to

http://mysite/Install/UnderConstruction.htm

Connection string is ok (I verified it).

Does anyone knows what should I do to make it work? Where to look, is it any log file or something where DNN might log what happens and why it doesn't start?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I tried again to do the migration. Actually, at the same time I was trying also to upgrade to a newer version (initila version was 4.(something), and upgraded to 5.(current)
I follow the instruction steps for upgrate from DNN site and I found that, initially, it seems I missed the step to set the permissions on the dnn folder on the new machine. After I set the permission and followed all other steps (installing db, setting db access user, editing connection string - which I did all before - and also **settings file system permissions**), the upgrade process went smooth and the dnn site is back up and running

I post this hoping it will help others in the same situation.

Thanks all of you for trying to help and regards!

Answer (score 0):

Are you the same URL as before, or are you using the name of the new box?  If it is the later, do you have a portal alias in DNN with that name?  Also, on the new box have you configured the binding for the site to include the server name you are using in the URL?

I've had very good success with DNN on 2008 (Win7 slightly more problematic), so it should "just work".

Comment: I'm using the same url as before. I have registered DNS which points to my network, and the lan is behind a home router, which forwards the requests on port 80 to a specific pc. I changed the settings in router to forward new requests to new virtual server, and on ikt I created a new site, which looks for exactly the same http header request (www.mydomain.com). The db is installed correctly (I verified I can connect to it using the user / pass I set in web.config), and the site actually starts, but instead of going to homepage, it automatically redirects me to /Install/Underconstruction.htm

Comment: Any thoughts what can cause this?

Comment: Everything I've seen points to a problem with the portal alias, or the database not having correct information for the install (the version table being for example).  But, if everything else is the same, the only difference I can think of would be the path to the site itself.  I'll poke around and see if DNN actually cares about that path anywhere.